# Void pointer values inexplicably changing between function calls

Tags: c, function, pointers, void

Okay, so the code I am referring to is below. It isn't the whole code, but it is the pertinent parts

```
void
array_sort(void *A, int arr_size, int comparison(void *, void*)) {
    void *max = A;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (comparison(A + i, max) == -1) {
            max = A + i;
        }
    }
}


int
num_ascending(void *n1, void *n2) {
    double v1 = *((double *) n1), v2 = *((double *) n2);
    if (v1 > v2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (v1 < v2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

The intent of the functions doesn't matter, and I have removed irrelevant parts, but the problem areas are above. My issue is that the user calls array_sort with an array of doubles and num_ascending as the comparison function. The problem is when the if statement is called, and it passes the addresses A + i and max to the comparison function, the values at the A + i location always changes to 0 if i is greater than 0, regardless of how big the original array A[] is.

The thing is, I've used a series of print statements to track a call. BEFORE the comparison call, the value at A + 1 is 1.00, and immediately within the call to num_ascending(), it reads as 0.00. I verified that the void pointer we're passing does not change, as in the address DOES get passed perfectly, but the value at that address has just gone to 0. It hasn't for the void* max. I'm just completely unsure as to why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `A + i` is not legal C. Your compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `A + i` is *conforming* C code, which is “legal” C. It is not *strictly conforming* code.

Comment: Why is A defined as `void *` instead of `double *`? For being a generic function like `qsort()` you need an additional parameter `size_t size`. The way it is defined you must know the member type anyway so using `void *` makes no sense

Comment: "*the values at the A + i location always changes to 0 if i is greater than 0*" -- that seems unlikely.  Nothing in the code presented modifies the object(s) to which `A` points.  Instead, what is happening is that the comparison function receives pointers that do not point to what it expects, as described in other comments and in your answer.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the keyword `void` is not some kind of magic wildcard.  It designates a *bona fide* distinct type all its own, although an "incomplete" one in the terminology of the language spec.

Comment: You should always provide a [mre] with debugging questions, even if you think this is only the relevant code. Providing a [mre] (a) Makes it easy for other people to reproduce the problem. (b) Proves this is the only relevant code. (c) Often reveals the problem before you post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's definitely worth using the same prototype as `qsort()` if you want to use it in the same generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering seems to stem from how you're accessing elements within the array of doubles in the array_sort function. Let's take a closer look at your array_sort function:

```
void array_sort(void *A, int arr_size, int comparison(void *, void*)) {
    void *max = A;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (comparison(A + i, max) == -1) {
            max = A + i;
        }
    }
}
```

When you add i to the void* A pointer in comparison(A + i, max), you're essentially moving the pointer forward by i times the size of the data type it points to. This might not be what you intend to do.

If A points to an array of doubles, incrementing A by i would move the pointer forward by i * sizeof(double) bytes, which is not what you want for accessing elements within the array.

Instead, you should use array indexing to access elements within the array. Here's how you can correct the array_sort function:

```
void array_sort(void *A, int arr_size, int comparison(void *, void*)) {
    void *max = A;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (comparison((char *)A + i * sizeof(double), max) == -1) {
            max = (char *)A + i * sizeof(double);
        }
    }
}
```

In this corrected version, we use i to index into the array by multiplying i with sizeof(double). This ensures that we're correctly accessing each element within the array of doubles. The cast to (char*) is necessary to perform pointer arithmetic properly, as incrementing a void* is not allowed in C.

Comment: why not `((double *)A) + i` instead of `(char *)A + i * sizeof(double)` ?

Comment: Re “When you add i to the void* A pointer in comparison(A + i, max), you're essentially moving the pointer forward by i times the size of the data type it points to.”: This is, at best, poorly worded. Pointer arithmetic is specified to add in units of the type that the **type** of `A` points to, not the type of the **data** that `A` points to. For example, if I have an array of `double` named `D` and set `char *p = (char ) D;`, then `p` points to `double` data but has type “pointer to `char`”. `p + i` adds using the type from the pointer, `char`, not the type from the data, `double`…

Comment: … And that brings us to the issue that the type o `A` is `void *`, and `void` is specified by the C standard to be an incomplete type (meaning its size is unknown) that cannot be completed. From the C standard alone, `A + i` is not defined, because it is not known what units to use. GCC and Clang have an extension that uses bytes for arithmetic with `void *`. And any answer needs to speak to that.

Comment: A better correction than either multiplying by `sizeof (double)` or casting to `double *` is (a) if the routine is intended to be generic, add a parameter providing the element size and multiply by that, or (b) if the routine is intended to be for `double`, declare the parameter to be `double *` instead of `void *`. If for some reason the parameter must be `void *` but the routine is for `double`, then a better correction is (c) declare the parameter as `void *vA` and, at the start of the function, define `double *A = vA;`, so `A` may be used normally inside the function. (Also, add `const`.)